# Complex Numbers: $1-z+z^2-z^3=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How to solve this equation? ($z$ is a complex number)

$1-z+z^2-z^3=0$

I tried using $z=a+ib$ and reached an answer but I'm not sure if it's a correct one.

Thanks!

Comment: I happen to see that $z=1$ is a solution...What do you think you can do with that?

Comment: If you think that you have an answer then you should be able to check it by plugging it in to the original equation

Answer (score 4):

$$1-z+z^2-z^3=(1-z)(1+z^2)=0$$
$$z=1,\pm i$$

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$1-z+z^2-z^3=0 $ is equivalent to $(1-z)(1+z^2)=0$,

then $(1-z)(i-z)(i+z)=0$. So, the solutions are:

$z=1$, $z=i$ or $z=-i$